# Laravel 5.6 Eloquent Optimizar Una consulta

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

necesito optimizar esto en el modelo

```
public function getPointStatsByUserId($id){
    return array(
        'total_win' => Trade::where('point' , '>', '0')
            ->where('user_id' , $id)
            ->sum('point'),
        'total_lose' => Trade::where('point' , '<', '0')
            ->where('user_id' , $id)
            ->sum('point')
    );
}
```

Esta realizando 2 consultas a la base de datos, quisiera saber si es posible hacerlo en 1 sola consulta... Gracias.

Comment: en la misma consulta necesitas que compare si el Modelo Trade tiene puntos mayores a cero y menores a cero?

Comment: la condicion suena rara.. un campo no puede valer esas dos cosas al mismo tiempo.. o sea, va a traer todos los campos menos el 0...

Comment: si, necesito la suma de todos los valores de la columna "point" positivos y tambien la suma de todos los valores negativos, actualmente funciona perfectamente pero quisiera saber si hay una forma de optimizarla, realizando una sola consulta a la BD en vez de 2

Comment: pues @kevinautam esa que pones es solo una consulta ya que solo veo que usas el modelo Trade